# playing sound from 3d position in java

Tags: java, javasound, java-3d

I would like to play a sound in java as if the source where moving on a sphere.

[image: spherical coordinates].

For example :

```
double rho = 2.0;
double theta = pi/6;
double phi = pi/12;
playSound("my_sound.mp3", rho, theta, phi);
```

I've never worked on playing sound in java, does anyone have a starting point?

Answer (score 3):

The three main techniques helpful for 3D will be the varying of amplitude, the varying of arrival time to each ear, and the manipulation of tone color (filtering).

You will need to work with the PCM values of the sound to do any of this, so knowing how to convert from the bytes to PCM and back is a necessary component.

It's a rather huge topic, and the amount of work that can be put into it is massive. A lot depends on what your goal is. If it's just to accompany a game or demo, normal panning and a bit of volume and filtering for the distance and height might suffice.